# How to rename dynamic symbols in arm elf .so file?

Tags: android, arm, reverse-engineering, elf, apk

I need to modify a so inside an Android APK. 
The task is to rename the dynamic symbols in side the so (which is the function name).

For example, change from Java_com_example_abc_.... to Java_com_yahoo_zzz_....

I try to use WinHex directly search and replace text words, the apk startup error. 
Seems like the .hash section also needs to be updated, but i do not know how to update the .hash section.

My question is what is the correct or preferable way to rename the dynamic Symbol?

I heave been stuck for 3 days, please help me, thank you very much!

Found a post might related, but he didn't gave the alternative solution.
https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2006-03/msg00266.html

Comment: the only way is to update the sources of your .so lib and compule it again

Comment: @pskink hmmm, i am lost now. The so file i am trying to modify is from another one, which is modified already from the original so. So i am pretty sure it's doable, but don't know how. Btw, just need to update the function name (symbol).

Comment: how do you know .so is already modified by someone else?

Comment: @pskink I extracted the .so from official package, also extracted the .so from the modified package. Then use the beyond compare to compare the hex value. I have uploaded the screenshot of the diff, please check.[link](http://i40.tinypic.com/2a8qgxw.jpg) http://i40.tinypic.com/2a8qgxw.jpg

Comment: @artlessnoise objcopy --redefine-syms ? No effects, and search on the internet someone say it's only redefine the oridinal symbols not dynamic symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I heave been stuck for 3 days, please help me,

What you are trying to achieve is *effectively* impossible.

ELF files have complicated internal structure, and what you want to do requires that you break it up and re-assemble the parts. An analogy would be to break an Intel CPU into transistors and re-assemble an AMD CPU from them.

> Found a post might related

It *is* related. Quote:

> Basically it does the following:
>
> 1. loop over .dynsym and re-create .dynstr
> 2. re-create the .hash table from scratch
> 3. calculate new lma/vma, new memory layout (.dynstr size changed!)
> 4. fix the contents of .dynamic, according to the new layout
> 5. fix .rel.dyn
> 6. fix .rel.plt
> 7. fix .dynsym again
> 8. write out the new section contents
>
> In copy_section: exclude the rewritten sections from being copyied.
>
> Currently it seems to create a syntactically valid ELF file, but as
> the distance between .plt and .got changes, the relative addressing in
> .plt is broken. Additionally the .got has to be fixed again.

So the author managed to glue together something that looks like an AMD CPU, but which doesn't work.

Sure, you can spend another 2 weeks to understand what the author did, and then another 3 weeks to fix the remaining broken pieces. And after that, you *may* get something that kind of sometimes works.

Your time is *likely* better spent elsewhere.

Comment: The related post is a patch attempting to rename symbols to be of a different length. If you don't need to change the length, then most of that work should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [LIEF](https://github.com/lief-project/LIEF), but try to keep them the same length

```py
native_lib = 'my_native_lib.so'
lib = lief.parse(native_lib)
for x in lib.exported_symbols:
    if x.name == 'Java_com_example_abc':
        x.name = 'Java_com_foobarr_zzz'
lib.write(native_lib)  # overwrite
```

Answer (score 0):

The ability to change names in shared libraries was added in Patchelf: https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf/commit/da035d6acee1e5a608aafe5f6572a67609b0198a

It should be available in the next release (after 0.17.2). Meanwhile you can build the tool following the instructions in https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf#compiling-and-testing

To use it, create a map file with two names (old and new) per line, and invoke Patchelf with:

```
$ patchelf --output libPatched.so --rename-dynamic-symbols map_file libOriginal.so
```

Please provide feedback if you find issues. Thanks!